# RadioButton click TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to set the state based on the radio button clicked.

My Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

 class MyApp extends Component {

    state={
        name: "SomeName",
        radio: "some"
        }

    onRadioChange(e) {
        this.setState({name:"New Name"});

        // this.setState({
        //  [e.target.name]: e.target.value;
        // })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div style={{marginBottom:"50px"}}>
                <input type="radio"     onChange = {this.onRadioChange}
                             value="JonSnow"
                             name="radio1" />
                <label>JonSnow</label>

                <input type="radio"   onChange = {this.onRadioChange}
                             value="Cleopatra"
                             name="radio1"/>
                <label>Cleopatra</label>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Whenever I click on the radio button, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here. Either use arrow function or bind your function to `this` inside your constructor.

**Why is it not working?**

This is because in order to use setState anywhere you must have access to `this`.

Arrow functions do not need to be explicitly bound to `this` and since is a shorter choice for achieving what you want. (They are bound to `this` beforehand).

**First option:**

```
onRadioChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ name: 'newName' });
```

}

**Second option:**

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onRadioChange = this.onRadioChange.bind(this);
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `this` keyword, you need to *bind* the method. Or as a workaround you can use the `arrow function`.

Like this:

```
onRadioChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({name:"New Name"});

        // this.setState({
        //  [e.target.name]: e.target.value;
        // })
    }
```